# Can't open my application from Openshift using Eclipse Java EE IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

After that I logged in to the Openshift from Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web, I'm getting the following error:

Could not load applications, cartridges and gears
Could not request https://hub.openshift.com/api/v1/quickstarts/promoted.json: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Please update you JDK if it is older than the one in this bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044060

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1219253

Could be a JDK version problem. Refer to the link above.